# How to create a method for a class that takes multiple objects of a class as arguments?

Tags: python, function, class, decorator, static-methods

I'd like to define a special method **within** a class that takes two instances of the class as arguments. I'd also like to be able to call this function with **`method(object_a, object_b)`** rather than `object_a.method(object_b)`. Let me illustrate with an example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def inside_class_age_diff(self, other):
        return abs(self.age - other.age)


def outside_class_age_diff(person_a, person_b):
    return abs(person_a.age - person_b.age)

Romeo = Person("Romeo", 20)
Juliet = Person("Juliet", 18)
print(Romeo.inside_class_age_diff(Juliet))
print(outside_class_age_diff(Romeo, Juliet))
```

So, in the above example `outside_class_age_diff()` takes two objects of the class `Person` as arguments, but it's defined outside of the class, which to me feels wrong because it's clearly a method that belongs to the class `Person`. On the other hand, even though `inside_class_age_diff()` is defined inside of the class, it needs to be called using the dot notation with an object of the class, which isn't very neat.

So, how can I get `inside_class_age_diff(Romeo, Juliet)` to work? Is it possible even?

Comment: But why does it belong in the class? To me, it seems like a perfectly reasonable module-level function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - If another programmer looks at my code and wants to use that class, surely it would be easier to see that my class offers that method, if it is defined in the same class. I think it adds structure to the code.

Comment: Why not the module? Modules are *for adding structure to your code*. And these sorts of functions that take objects of classes defined in the function is typical of many python modules. Take for example the standard library module `fractions`. The module has two classes, `fractions.Fraction` and `fractions.Decimal`. There is a module-level function `fractions.gcd` that takes two objects of the `fractions.Fraction` class and finds their greatest common divisor.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah I see! I'm mixing multiple classes that aren't overly related within the same module, which is why it felt unstructured to put things outside of a class. But, I can see how splitting it into various modules will help me maintain clarity. Thanks for that example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're playing around with design patterns. What you're looking for is a [static method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

You'd define it like so:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        ...

    def inside_class_age_diff(self, other):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def outside_class_age_diff(person_a, person_b):
        return abs(person_a.age - person_b.age)
```

You can then use it like so:

```
Person.inside_class_age_diff(Romeo, Juliet)
```

It's still a method of the class, and thus needs to be called as such.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'outside_class_age_diff' is not defined` using that code with `print(outside_class_age_diff(Romeo, Juliet))`.  Does it work for you? :(

Comment: @blueprince13, you need to call it like `Person.outside_class_age_diff(Romeo, Juliet)`. It's still a method of the class, so it needs to be called as such.

Comment: Got you! That works now, and is what I wanted. :)  Could you please add that to your answer, just for anyone else who may stumble upon this?

Comment: If the method will access private attributes and methods of the class/object should it still be staticmethod or rather classmethod?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a static method:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @staticmethod    
    def inside_class_age_diff(person_a, person_b):
        return abs(person_a.age - person_b.age)



Romeo = Person("Romeo", 20)
Juliet = Person("Juliet", 18)
print(Romeo.inside_class_age_diff(Romeo, Juliet))
```

A static method acts just like normal function, i.e. it is not bound to an instance. Hence the first argument, is not treated special in any way.